# perl match consecutive newlines: `echo "aaa\n\n\nbbb" | perl -pe "s/\\n\\n/z/gm"`

Tags: regex, perl

This works:

```bash
echo "aaa\n\n\nbbb" | perl -pe "s/\\n/z/gm"

aaazzzbbbz
```

This doesn't match anything:

```bash
echo "aaa\n\n\nbbb" | perl -pe "s/\\n\\n/z/gm"

aaa


bbb
```

How do I fix, so the regex matches two consecutive newlines?

Comment: Double-quotes are parsed by shell before perl sees the  content. `"\\n"` means perl sees `\n`.

Comment: Your first example doesn't do what you claim, although it will if you use single-quotes

Comment: also, `echo` does not expand `\n` by default, so your second example doesn't output what you show either

Comment: Using echo like this to test code is likely to create interpolation confusion. It is unlikely that this is the way you intend to use the code, so perhaps instead use it as file input, either inline with the `___DATA___` file handle, or by using a file with input, e.g. `perl -pe "s....." testfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linefeed is matched by `\n`

```
echo "a\n\n\b" | perl -pe's/\n/z/'
```

This prints `azzb`, and without the following newline, so with the next prompt on the same line.  Note that the program is fed one line at a time so there is no need for `/g` modifier.  (And which is why `\n\n` doesn't match.)  That `/m` modifier is then unrelated to this example.<sup>†</sup>

I don't know in what form this is used but I'd imagine not with `echo` feeding the input?  Then better test it with input in a file, or in a multi-line string (in which case `/g` may be needed).

An example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

# Test with multiline string  
my $ml_str = "a\n\nb\n";

$ml_str =~ s/\n/z/g;  #-->  azzbz (no newline at the end)
print $ml_str;    
say '';      # to terminate the line above

# Or to replace two consecutive newlines (everywhere)
$ml_str = "a\n\nb\n";   # restore the example string 
$ml_str =~ s/\n\n/z/g;  #-->  azb\n
print $ml_str;    


# To replace the consecutive newlines in a file read it into a string
my $file = join '', <DATA>;  # lines of data after __DATA__

$file =~ s/\n\n/z/g;
print $file;  

__DATA__
one
two


last
```

This prints

```
azzbz
azb
one
twoz
last
```

---

As a side note, I'd like to mention that with the modifier `/s`  the `.` matches a newline as well.  (For example, this is handy for matching substrings that may contain newlines by `.*` (or `.+`); without `/s` modifier that pattern stops at a newline.)

See [perlrebackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash) and search for `newline`.

---

<sup>†</sup> The `/m` modifier makes `^` and `$` also match beginning and end of lines *inside* a multi-line string. Then

```
$multiline_string =~ s/$/z/mg;
```

will replace newlines inside the string.  However, this example bears some complexities since some of the newlines stay.

Comment: I don't want to match everything including new lines, I just want to match new lines. Also, what's wrong with using echo to pipe in input for a super simple test?

Comment: @clay "_don't want to match everything_" -- yeah, obviously; I mentioned `.` just in one side comment at the very end (since it _does_ match newline with `/s`).  Nothing is _wrong_ with using `echo` (I often do) but in this case there are issues with newlines (since `echo` interpretes them and thus sends separate lines to the program).  That's all.  I just think it's  better to test _this_ in a realistic setting

Answer (score 0):

You are applying substitution to only one line at a time, and one line will never have two newlines.  Apply the substitution to the entire file instead:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\n/z/g'
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `echo "aaa\n\nbbb" | perl -0777 -pe 's/\\n\\n/z/g'`

Comment: @clay  Lose the double backslashes; just `\n`

Comment: oops, sorry, fixed